# Support for collation in JPA criteria API

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I need to add "COLLATE" to my search query to sort the data according to the user's language;I'm using JPA/Hibernate and HSQLDB. However, I don't find any direct option to add "COLLATE" support to the query using the Criteria API. One possible way to do this is to unwrap the TypedQuery to Hibernate query, get the query string, explicitly modify, and rebuild the TypedQuery.Nevertheless, I'd like to know if there is any other cleaner approach to achieve the same without deviating from Criteria API.  For example, I'd like to generate the following SQL query:

**SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY name COLLATE "Chinese"**

Comment: There is no such JPQL keyword. Native queries is the way

Comment: Do you have to depend upon a language-specific collate on the database side? A collation like `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (in MySQL) can most likely be used with any unicode encoding (`utf8mb4` is only available since MySQL 5.5.3).

Comment: @Tiny We are using HSQLDB and our requirement is to sort the data based on the user's locale;unicode way of sorting may not be correct for some languages or is it? Is there any other way of doing this without sending COLLATE in the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of collation into a JPA criteria query. With MySQL DB :

```
private Predicate predicateOfString(String criteria, Path<String> fieldPath) {
        return getCriteriaBuilder().like(
                getCriteriaBuilder().function("collate_ai_ci", String.class, fieldPath),
                "%" + criteria + "%"
        );
    }
```

Of Course, table (or column) need to be explicity created with **COLLATE** keyword. Ex. liquibase script (generate mysql code) :

```
<sql dbms="mysql">
            CREATE TABLE configuration
            (
                id           BIGINT auto_increment NOT NULL,
                config_key   varchar(100) NULL,
                config_value varchar(100) NULL,
                primary key (id),
                unique key uk_configuration (config_key)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB
            DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
            COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;
        </sql>
```

Comment: hum ... interesting ... but no sure I understand the Path parameter (fieldPath) used in the function("collate_ai_ci", String.class, fieldPath) ... could you elaborate ... I'm trying to do the same thing in postgres   ... "  where field like '%expr%' collate "fr-CA-x-icu"